# Storing DateTimeOffset for Timezone sensitive application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timezone

If I store all my dates using DateTimeOffset will I still need to always convert the date to UTC, or will it be efficient to only have the DateTimeOffset?

Comment: You should always store the actual time zone string, not a offset value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is - it depends.

`DateTimeOffset` is a timestamp + UTC Offset. The problem is that multiple timezones can share the same offset, but they might not share the same Daylight Saving rules (among other things) and since `DateTimeOffset` does not have any notion of TimeZone it leads to ambiguity. However that might be fine if you are storing server side timestamps, which are not displayed to the user and the user has no interaction with. An example of that could be server side logging I guess.

IMHO the safest approach when dealing with user input, user visible, user queryable, etc, etc timestamps is to store `DateTime`s and store the full timezone information. You can use `TimeZoneInfo.Serialize(...)`, which outputs the full timezone info to a string and persist it in the database and which you can later deserialize to a TimeZoneInfo instance via `TimeZoneInfo.Deserialize(...)` and use to convert `DateTime` to local/utc datetime. It is safe, because there is no ambiguity and also even if a timezone changes (and they do - e.g. DST changes) your data is still consistent. Of course you will need to take care of updating your database to keep it in sync (quite rare).

With the above approach you can either save the DateTimes in UTC or Local and you have to decide which one depending on the use case. One funny thing when storing dates and times in UTC is that the notion of user's "Today" gets slightly more complicated - you can read about that on my blog [here](http://ivanz.com/2011/04/04/storing-date-and-time-in-utc-and-the-definition-today/).

Comment: Nice answer. Just an update for newer versions on .NET. `TimeZoneInfo.Serialize(...)` is now `tzInstance.ToSerializedString()` and `TimeZoneInfo.Deserialize(...)` is now TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString(...)`